# Use whizzyTeX with emacs on Windows

Tags: emacs, windows

today I know [whizzyTeX](http://cristal.inria.fr/whizzytex/) can be use with Emacs on Windows. But I don't know how to install it. Can anyone help me install whizzyTeX on Windows?. I had installed 24.2.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment. The instructions I had were for the Mac...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently WhizzyTeX runs under Cygwin (1.5.5-1) using Cygwin/Xfree 4.3 and xdvi from teTeX 2.0.2-13. This requires several modifications according to the [WhizzyTeX FAQ](http://cristal.inria.fr/whizzytex/FAQ.html#htoc5). instead of repeating the installation steps here, please refer to the [WhizzyTeX FAQ](http://cristal.inria.fr/whizzytex/FAQ.html#htoc5).

There was a [SourceForge project to port WhizzyTeX to Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winwhizzytex/)  but that seems to have stagnated.

Comment: but I don't understand. Can you help me install step by step. I'm very very thank you so much!

Comment: Maybe you could expand your question with the different steps of the installation and point out which steps you have problems with?